# Dialog presented with UIModalPresentationFormSheet style in popover controller of split view disappeared after rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I use split view in my app, and I present a dialog with UIModalPresentationFormSheet style in popover controller in portrait mode, but after I rotate to landscape mode the dialog disappeared automatically. I don't want it disappear, I would like user could use the dialog after rotation, what can I do?

I found that if I present the dialog in landscape mode for the 1st time, the dialog wouldn't disappear after rotating to portrait mode, it's strange.

Any hints or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I solved this issue in this way:
Present the view from the split view controller instead of popover, and the view won't disappear any more whenever I rotate the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue in this way:
present the view from the split view controller instead of popover, and the view won't disappear any more whenever I rotate the device

Answer (score 3):

iOS will try and automatically relocate the view, but it depends on where the popover is presented from.  From the docs

> If the user rotates the device while a popover is visible, the popover
>   controller hides the popover and then shows it again at the end of the
>   rotation. The popover controller attempts to position the popover
>   appropriately for you but you may have to present it again or hide it
>   altogether in some cases. For example, when displayed from a bar
>   button item, the popover controller automatically adjusts the position
>   (and potentially the size) of the popover to account for changes to
>   the position of the bar button item. However, if you remove the bar
>   button item during the rotation, or if you presented the popover from
>   a target rectangle in a view, the popover controller does not attempt
>   to reposition the popover. In those cases, you must manually hide the
>   popover or present it again from an appropriate new position. You can
>   do this in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method of the view
>   controller that you used to present the popover.

Comment: I don't mean the popover view, I mean another view presented from the popover view in portrait mode, the view disappeared after rotating to landscape mode.